# how to write one to many relationship in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I am using `EF CodeFirst` approach for quite long. This is how I used to define one to many relationship.

```
//one Customer can have many products --> One to Many relationship.
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdId { get; set; }
    public string BuyDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

But recently while one discussion, I came to know that this is not the best approach. There is a way where I can define such relationship without overhead of `public int CustomerId { get; set; }` in Product Entity.

How do I do this?

Comment: By adding the property `public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }` to your `Product` class would be enough.

Comment: @dcg, Suppose I do so.Then suppose I need the all customer & their products where custId = 10. How will it identify which product belong to which customer

Comment: when you have the instance of the `Product`, the reference to the `Customer` is properly set so you get the right customer.

Answer (score 1):

When you define the relationship as following it should be enough to create a one-to-many relationship between product and customer

```
public class Customer
{
    //other properties omitted
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    //other properties omitted
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

In EF you can then set this relationship (for a new product) in the following ways:

```
var customer = context.Customers.GetById(1);
var myProduct = new Product()
{
    //set all the properties
}

customer.Products.Add(myProduct);
context.SaveChanges();
```

When you have loaded a product with EF, you can acces the customer (and all its properties) just by navigating to it:

```
string name = myProduct.Customer.CustName;
int custId = myProduct.Customer.Id;
```

note that querying the products dbset and looking at the customerId causes the generated SQL to perform a join to the customers table which can have a negative effect on performance.

I don't find your example to be a bad solution. I think that in some cases it makes sense to include the CustomerId in your model (it is created in the database anyway by EF to create the relationship).

Comment: Yes. When I run the migration command & see the table structure in database it has generated the same CustomerID column in table

Comment: Does this explanation answer your question or is there anything left I should explain?

Comment: Yes. to a good extent. But what I see is that in your post, you still have included  `public int CustomerId { get; set; }`.in Product Entity. AlsoI am looking to get some answers from others.Meanwhile I am upvoting your post

Comment: Yes however it can also be omitted. I included it to show that you should decorate it with [foreignKey] to ensure that entity framework doesn't create duplicate columns. I think it is a good practice to include the CustomerId property. See my statement about the joins in SQL.

Comment: Yes. I read that impact statement of yours. Lets wait for sometime in case I didn't get better ans, I will mark this as accepted. Hope its fine to you :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the `CustomerId` property from `Product`, and rename the primary key in `Customer` to `CustomerId`.